# Does a targets-permutation test prove that regression find a real pattern?

Tags: machine-learning, p-value, overfitting, noise

I need to solve a standard ("vanilla") regression problem meaning that I have a 2D array of real-valued features (`X`) and 1D array of real-valued targets (`Y`). I use this data to train a simple regression model (let say a linear model or a simple decision tree).

Since my data are very noisy, I am not sure that there is any pattern in the data at all. In other words, it might be the case, that what I have is only noise and there is absolutely no dependency of my targets on my features. To exclude this possibility, I came up with the idea of the following test:

1. I randomly permute all my targets so that, per construction, I destroy any possible relation between features and targets. For example, the first features-vector gets 137-th target, the second features-vector gets 34-th target and so on.
2. I use these (fake, synthetic) data to fit my model again and I record its accuracy (for example squared deviation).
3. Then I permute my targets again and run a fit again. I do it 10 000 times and check how often my accuracy on "fake" (synthetic) data is as good as, or even better, than accuracy achieved on real (original) data.

I was happy with this test. I said that, if accuracies obtained on the "fake" data is almost never better than accuracy achieved on the "real" data, then we can say that there is some dependency of targets on features in my data set. So, my model does something meaningful and not just overfitting by finding some "fake" patterns in pure noise.

However, I am not sure anymore about my interpretation. I guess that the only thing that I prove, is that the distribution of targets depends on features and it does not necessarily mean that the mean of this features-dependent distribution depends on features!

By minimising squared deviation I search dependency of mean on targets but my test probably does not guaranty that the found dependency of mean on features makes any sense. Maybe mean is not features dependent but standard deviation (or kurtosis, or skewness or other property of distribution) is and, this is why accuracy achieved on the real data is almost always better than accuracy achieved on the fake data.

Are my concerns valid?

Answer (score 3):

Your idea does work.
This can be viewed as a type of Monte Carlo simulation where you randomly pick a set of points from the target distribution and regress to them, and you get a distribution of MSE. you can then check if the MSE you get for the real target distribution is significantly lower than from a randomly assigned distribution.

The common way of doing it is called "permutation feature importance" where you shuffle a feature instead of the target, and it's used mainly for nonlinear estimators like trees, random forests, etc.

It would be better though to actually randomly assign targets from the distribution of targets and not just permuting them.

But I'm not sure why you would do this instead of just checking that the regression coefficients you get are significantly greater than zero for linear regression.

Comment: but to be precise, my test tells me not more than the following: "If there is no dependency on features, it is almost impossible to get such good results as you have." Thats' it. But it is too weak statement. It does not guaranty me that mean depends on features.

Comment: You are still performing a linear regression analysis that shows that the mean of the target is dependent on the mean of the features.

The test only shows that your result is unlikely to be caused by chance.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>There are some issues with the type of used cost functions. For these issues see a previous [second version of this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/revisions/559295/2). The current question is edited.</sup>

Your first fit already determined an *effect* that the mean is dependent on the features. Or at least expressing the mean as a linear function of the regressors gives a lower mean squared error than expressing the mean as a constant (and this indicates that a linear function is closer to the true mean of the population and a zero effect is not the true model).

The question that the permutations answer is not whether there is an effect and what the effect is (whether it is a difference in the mean or another difference in the distribution) but whether the observed effect is statistically significant. Statistically significant means that the observed effect in unlikely occuring in repeated experiments with different samples/data. These repeated experiments is what you simulated with the permutations.

If there is anything wrong with your method then it is not that the effect is not about the mean but that the significance might not be well approximated by permutations.

- For instance: is your data a collection of independent samples? If you have for example only two types of data points (say you measure a lot of people, but they are all from only two villages or other categories) and these are repeated many times, then your sample is effectively very small (it may not need to be about the number of observed people but instead about the number of observed villages). The same datapoints repeated many times in slightly different form makes you overestimate the sample size and you can easily get a false idea of a significant effect

Comment: I minimise the mean square error (MSE) and, therefore, I interpret predictions of my model as mean. My concern is a follows: The MSE on the original (real) data is almost never reached on "fake" data (where dependency on features destroyed by either permutation or resampling of targets). However, I am not sure that this fact proves that I have dependency of mean on features in the real data.

Comment: Sorry, but you seem to answer another question. My question is not about minimising different measure. My question is about a permutation / resampling test.

Comment: @Roman the answer is dependent on your cost function. You did not specify this in your question and in my answer I explain why this is important. It also relates specifically to the quoted question. Maybe you should explain why you believe that you *"the only thing that I prove, is that the distribution of targets depends on features"* but that this does not relate to the mean *" it does not necessarily mean that the mean of this features-dependent distribution depends on features"*. I explain that this depends on the cost function....

Comment: ... What do you want to have explained here? if you believe that your data shows that the distribution is feature dependent, why don't you have this same believe that the mean is feature dependent?

Comment: My cost function is MSE. By minimising MSE on the real data set I get good (small) MSE that I almost never get on the "fake" data set. So, one might be tempted to say that the mean really depend on the feature.  However, the only think that I can do is to reject the null hypothesis that state that distribution is features independent. Obviously, the fact that the distribution is features dependent does not guaranty that mean is features dependent.

Comment: In other words, how can I be sure, that the good (small) MSE observed on the real data set is caused by the fact that mean depends on the feature? I want to know the probability that such a good MSE could be obtained by chance under the assumption that mean is features independent. And my test does not answer this question since in addition to features independent mean it assumes other things, namely that the whole distribution (std, skewness, kurtosis) is features independent.

Comment: @Roman could you update this in your question explaining that waht sort of regression you are talking about and what sort of validation you use.

Comment: @Roman also explain which assumptions you make about skewness kurtosis etc. I don't read in the question that you make any assumptions.

Comment: My question is not regression specific. It does not meter if it is a linear regression or, let's say, decision tree. The validation procedure is already described in the question. I do not make any assumptions about skewness and kurtosis. They can be anything and they can arbitrary depend on features.

Comment: @Roman it does matter what sort of regression you apply. For instance when you are using quantile regression (depending on the mean absolute error). I gave an example where you can get more likely a significant effect while there is no true dependence of the mean.

Comment: In your new version of the answer you write: "the observed effect in unlikely occurring in repeated experiments with different samples". But the experiment represents a specific null hypothesis, which is "distribution is features independent". Under this assumption it is indeed unlikely. However, maybe there is a features dependent distribution for which mean is features independent and maybe for this distribution my results a likely. So, maybe my good fit could happen even if true mean is constant.

Comment: @Roman *"but the experiment represent a specific null hypothesis"* why do you believe that this is refering to 'the distribution being features dependent' but not to 'the mean being features dependent'....

Comment: ...a problem with this question is that multiple issues get together at once and it is not clear which one is the core of the question that needs to be resolved. It would be better to bring down the issue/question to a more simple single issue with a **representable** example that is focussed on a single issue. One problem with the current question is that permutations have much problems on their own. If you would explain mote explicitly your original problem instead of this abstract question, then possibly it might be easier to understand what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: ... A reason why I highlightee 'representable' is also because this would make your question, which is at least confusing to me, more practical/tangible and easier to understand.

Comment: Q: "why do you believe that this is refering to 'the distribution being features dependent' but not to 'the mean being features dependent". A: Because the null hypothesis states that distribution does not depend on features.  If the null hypothesis is rejected, than we can say that the distribution is features dependent but we do not know if its mean is features dependent. So, we have no reason to believe that mean is features dependent. We also do not have reasons to believe that it is features independent. The only thing that we know is that distribution is features dependent.

Comment: Permutations are not essential to my question. As I have written in my question, we can use resampling instead of permutation. The main idea is that we perform fits on randomised ("fake") data where target does not depend on features per construction and check what accuracy we can achieve (by chance) in this case.

Comment: My question is very specific, I guess. It is: How to design a non-parametric test whose possible outcome might be a rejection of null hypothesis stating that mean is independent on features.

Comment: *"Because the null hypothesis states that distribution does not depend on features"* Where does this null hypothesis come from? I do not see this specified in your question, and it is not implied by your test. When you perform an ordinary least squares regression, then this does not relate to any difference in distributions, and instead it relates more specifically to a difference in the means (without regards to any other difference that might be present).

Comment: Per construction, the targets in my "fake" datasets are coming from almost the same distribution as targets in the "real" dataset (be cause I resample from the real targets). Also per construction, in my "fake" data set there is no dependency of (distribution of) targets on features. In my test I use the "fake" datasets to I check how often I reach my reference MSE (the "real" one). This is how I test my null hypothesis (distribution of targets do not depend on features).

Comment: In my "fake" datasets, mean, as well as other parameters of distribution, do not depend on features but from time to time I can reach good (small) MSE just by chance. My worry is that there are some features dependent distributions for which mean is features independent and for these distributions I can reach good (small) MSE by chance more frequently. And I am afraid that this is what happens in reality.

Comment: @Roman I only see a construction where you model the means. When you test the model with least squares error then this is a test of the accuracy of the mean, it is the mean that minimises the expectation of this error and other statistics do not do that. Your reasoning is a bit circular: the statement *"This is how I test my null hypothesis"* does not explain that this null hypothesis means the general 'the distributions are different'. You can bring it down to the more specific 'the means of the distributions are different'.

Comment: The model that expresses the mean is the  model that minimises least squares. When you find that the fit is not a model where the means are all the same then you found out that there is an effect in the means. The question indeed remains whether it is significant, but it is about the means and not about other distribution parameters.

Comment: The permutations complicate it a bit because it adds an extra layer of complexity to the question. Because the permutations might be a bad representation of the true distribution, it can be possible that the significance that you compute is wrong. But you could rephrase the question to a simpler case where you consider a situation where you could directly sample the population. In that case you can not have that a model that fits with different means performs significantly better (for a cost that is mean squared error) if there is no true effect of the means.

Comment: Yes, I know that minimisation of squared error gives mean.  Yes, I want to know if dependency of mean on feature is significant (I do not care about other parameters of the distribution). But! In my test I simulate a null hypothesis in which NOTHING depends on features. And then I reject this hypothesis. So, I can conclude that SOMETHING depends on features. But it does not mean that mean depends on features. Maybe it is STD or skewness of kurtosis (or all of them, but not the mean). I have no prove that mean is features dependent. But I also do not have prove that it is features independent.

Comment: Since your estimation procedure minimizes MSE, the permutation test can only detect differences in the means.  So you can conclude that the mean depends on features.  Other parameters may or may not; the mean definitely does, because that's what your procedure is estimating.  Try multiplying all the data by $2$; you will get exactly the same result, although the std. deviation is 2x as big.... the procedure doesn't care, writing anthropomorphically, because what it cares about is the mean.